# Trying to remove parent container of slide made by Slick Slider Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have made a filter that hides a certain class in a slick slider based on the objects data-tag and the checkbox's value. When the class is hidden, it still leaves a blank space open because it should actually hide the parent container made by the slick slider.

EXAMPLE - If you are on the first slide page and you select "Truck", the trucks will not show up. But if you go to the next page and select truck, you will see all the trucks.

If I can just hide the parent container which is made by the plugin(See image below), the rest of the slides will fall into place and make the correct amount of slides and slide pages.

I have added a image of the outputted slider structure with the class that has to be hidden - [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A7iF.png)

I have inserted the plugin along with the filter. I have also made comments highlighting the objects that need to be dealt with.

See snippet below -

```js
//MODEL FILTER FUNCTION

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mo-type-check').on('change', function(){
    var category_list = [];
    $('#filters :input:checked').each(function(){
      var category = $(this).val();
      category_list.push(category);
    });

    if(category_list.length == 0){
        $('.resultblock').fadeIn();
    }
        
    else {
      $('.resultblock').each(function(){
        var item = $(this).attr('data-tag');
        if(jQuery.inArray(item,category_list) > - 1) //Check if data-tag's value is in array
          $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        else
          $(this).hide();
      });
    }
    });
    
});

$('.mo-slide').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      rows: 2,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="0" role="button">▸</button>',
      nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" role="button">▸</button>',
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 912,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: false,
            dots: true
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul id="filters">
                  <li>
                    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="convert" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check1">Convertable</label>
                    <label for="check1" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="hatch" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check2">Hatchback</label>
                    <label for="check2" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check" value="sedan" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check3">Sedan</label>
                    <label for="check3" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li>
                    <input id="check4" type="checkbox" name="check" value="coupe" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check4">Coupe</label>
                    <label for="check4" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li>
                    <input id="check5" type="checkbox" name="check" value="suv" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check5">SUV</label>
                    <label for="check5" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li>
                    <input id="check6" type="checkbox" name="check" value="wag" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check6">Wagon</label>
                    <label for="check6" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li>
                    <input id="check7" type="checkbox" name="check" value="truck" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check7">Truck</label>
                    <label for="check7" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li>
                    <input id="check8" type="checkbox" name="check" value="van" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check8">Van</label>
                    <label for="check8" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                
                            <div class="mo-slide" id="mo-slide">
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="convert">
                    <img src="img/convert.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Convertable</p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="hatch">
                    <img src="img/hatchback.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Hacthback</p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="sedan">
                   <img src="img/sedan.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Sedan</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="coupe">
                   <img src="img/coupe.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Coupe</p>
                  </div>
                  
                   <div class="resultblock" data-tag="suv">
                    <img src="img/suv.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">SUV</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="wag">
                    <img src="img/wagon.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Wagon</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="truck">
                    <img src="img/truck.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Truck</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="van">
                    <img src="img/van.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Van</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="truck">
                    <img src="img/truck.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Truck</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="van">
                    <img src="img/van.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Van</p>
                  </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your containers have a `min-height` of 1px.  Add the following CSS to reset it to 0.

```
.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
    min-height: 0;
}
```

```js
//MODEL FILTER FUNCTION

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mo-type-check').on('change', function(){
    var category_list = [];
    $('#filters :input:checked').each(function(){
      var category = $(this).val();
      category_list.push(category);
    });

    if(category_list.length == 0){
        $('.resultblock').fadeIn();
    }
        
    else {
      $('.resultblock').each(function(){
        var item = $(this).attr('data-tag');
        if(jQuery.inArray(item,category_list) > - 1) //Check if data-tag's value is in array
          $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        else
          $(this).hide();
      });
    }
    });
    
});

$('.mo-slide').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      rows: 2,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="0" role="button">▸</button>',
      nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" role="button">▸</button>',
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 912,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: false,
            dots: true
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    .slick-initialized .slick-slide {
        min-height: 0;
    }
</style>
<ul id="filters">
                  <li>
                    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="convert" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check1">Convertable</label>
                    <label for="check1" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="hatch" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check2">Hatchback</label>
                    <label for="check2" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check" value="sedan" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check3">Sedan</label>
                    <label for="check3" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li>
                    <input id="check4" type="checkbox" name="check" value="coupe" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check4">Coupe</label>
                    <label for="check4" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li>
                    <input id="check5" type="checkbox" name="check" value="suv" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check5">SUV</label>
                    <label for="check5" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li>
                    <input id="check6" type="checkbox" name="check" value="wag" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check6">Wagon</label>
                    <label for="check6" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li>
                    <input id="check7" type="checkbox" name="check" value="truck" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check7">Truck</label>
                    <label for="check7" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li>
                    <input id="check8" type="checkbox" name="check" value="van" class="mo-type-check">
                    <label for="check8">Van</label>
                    <label for="check8" class="selection"></label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                
                            <div class="mo-slide" id="mo-slide">
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="convert">
                    <img src="img/convert.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Convertable</p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="hatch">
                    <img src="img/hatchback.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Hacthback</p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="sedan">
                   <img src="img/sedan.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Sedan</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="coupe">
                   <img src="img/coupe.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Coupe</p>
                  </div>
                  
                   <div class="resultblock" data-tag="suv">
                    <img src="img/suv.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">SUV</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="wag">
                    <img src="img/wagon.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Wagon</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="truck">
                    <img src="img/truck.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Truck</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="van">
                    <img src="img/van.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Van</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="truck">
                    <img src="img/truck.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Truck</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="resultblock" data-tag="van">
                    <img src="img/van.png" class="mo-img">
                    <p class="mo-desc">Van</p>
                  </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Man... Do I feel like a real idiot. I have been struggling with this the whole weekend.. Trying things in Jquery and then it turns out to be a simple css rule! Thank you sn3ll!

Comment: No prob.  Happens to the best of us ;-)